# Geotransform data missing in L2A products on S3

Tags: coordinate-system, sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use Sentinel-2 L2A tiles from the `sentinel-s2-l2a` bucket. Unfortunately I noticed that the geotransform information (SRS, origin, scale, and skew) are missing on the tile files.

An example image is the following:

```
tiles/32/T/LS/2017/6/22/0/R10m/B03.jp2
```

Why do the L2A tiles not have the Geotransform specified?

Comment: Have you tried https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products? What did you find and what do you miss?

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: Is the geotransform information present in the L2A data available from the [Copernicus Hub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/)? It should be the same data as on AWS - since Sinergise ingests it from the Copernicus Hub into AWS.

Comment: I did check on a few images on SciHub and those are properly georeferenced.

Comment: L2A data are actually changed a bit after ingestion as we wanted to make them technically the same as L1C, which is (or at least was) not the case. Specifically a precint configuration is (was) different. We were told that this recently changed and if it is correct, re-encoding is no longer necessary. There is a chance that geotransform information were lost in the process. We will take investigate this and come back with findings. We apologize for inconvenience.

Comment: @GregaM. Thanks for clearing that up! Please consider adding your comment as an answer - I doubt anyone will be able to provide a better answer, given that your company handles the ingestion.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @GregaM. ! I can second the comment above, do consider post your comment / update as answer.